# GetModuleInformation() function returned address and size information

Tags: winapi

GetModuleHandle(), GetModuleInformation() return address and size information on all the loaded modules in an app.  I am only interested in the first module (exe) but when using ReadProcessMemory() and calling it more than once (using the same handles and process ID) and comparing the passes I get a few differences each time.

I was expecting memory address returned to be just a code segment however this appears not to be the case.  Does the module memory address and size returned by GetModuleInformatiob() include code and data?

I have tried looking around for a full description on the windows app load process but cannot find anything.

Comment: Note that I changed your tags, just as I did in your previous question. This isn't a Delphi question, it's a winapi question.

Comment: And some more.  Depends on the toolset that was used to build the module, but most of them generate at least a .text and .data section.  Get insight by running dumpbin.exe /headers on the file.

Comment: What's the relation between `GetModuleHandle` and `ReadProcessMemory`? The former only ever returns a reasonable result when called in context of the process that loaded the module, whereas the latter is only really useful, when reaching across process boundaries. Something about this question doesn't sound right.

Comment: Agreed, I only need CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() and Module32First() to get the first module info, ReadProcessMemory is not needed as the memory is already accessible.  You are right, it isn't right, I have found out more since it was written.  The next problem is sorting out the memory range for just text.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the module memory address and size returned by GetModuleInformation() include code and data?

Yes.

Comment: I'm sorry that this is such a concise answer, but there's really very little more that can be said.

Comment: No problem with a concise answer.  It has persuaded me to abandon (somewhat disappointedly) the path that I was taking as I don't have enough info to go forward.